# How do you encrypt data while performing a mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5, mysqldump, encryption, command-line

My OS is windows 7.

- How can I encrypt data while performing a mysqldump?
- From the command prompt, can I take a mysqldump with encrypted varchar and texts values?

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: This is a shout out to everyone answering this question to supply a Windows 7 based answer. If you have Windows-based encryption tools, please readjust your answers where possible

Comment: We use MySQLBackupFTP http://mysqlbackupftp.com it performs backups via mysqldump and has the encryption option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encrypt your mysqldump data in windows try the following command at the command prompt:

```
 mysqldump *databaseName* > *dbNameBackup.sql* && cipher /e /a *dbNameBackup.sql*
```

Comment: Excuse me for executing this command any other application I need to install? Also I need to encrypt only varchar and text fields. By using this command can I do like that? Thanks.

Comment: @learner You do not need to install any extra application for this. Cipher comes with Windows. This will encrypt the whole file. To encrypt only certain columns, you will have to do it before backing up.

Comment: how to decrypt using cipher?

Comment: @learner to decrypt do: cipher /d /a dbNameBackup.sql

Answer (score 7):

You can use `ccrypt`. Example:

- Creating the key file:

  ```
  echo 'mySecretKey123' > ~/.backup.key
  chmod 600 ~/.backup.key
  ```
- Encrypting the backup:

  ```
  mysqldump databasename | ccrypt -k ~/.backup.key | bzip -c > ~/backup-mysql.sql.bz2.cpt
  ```
- To decrypt the backup:

  ```
  cat ~/backup-mysql.sql.bz2.cpt | ccat -k ~/.backup.key | bunzip2 -c | less
  ```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you are using Windows. The example above is for Linux...

Answer (score 1):

Using a password inside the script is a really bad idea as this can be seen in `ps aux` and read out by every system user.

I would suggest you to look into [mysqldump-secure](https://github.com/cytopia/mysqldump-secure). This is a shell script that does `openssl` encryption based on public-private key encryption and is a lot more performant than gpg. Additionally it will compress your databases and writes a log file of success/failure. It also ships with a nagios plugin that will let you know any problems that happened during the dump.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL file encryption & decryption command line:

- encryption:

  ```
  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in /path/example.sql -out /path/example.file
  ```
- decryption:

  ```
  openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in /path/example.file > /path/example.sql
  ```